# How can I remove part of the path from incoming URL in Nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx

Here is my requirement. I need to check each incoming request to see if it starts with a valid locale (lang) and if so, I need to remove it from the path and add it as an HTTP header field and pass the request.

The list of valid languages is dynamic. For example, a website might support `en`, `fr` and `ru`. The default language does not have prefixes in the URLs. For example `example.tld/blog`. For this URL, I would simply add `Locale: en` to the HTTP request header fields and pass the request.

But for a link like `example.tld/fr/blog`, I need to convert it to `example.tld/blog` and add `Locale: fr` to the HTTP request's header fields, and then pass the request.

In other words, I want to know the language in my Nginx reverse proxy, and pass it in another form to the upstream server.

I have no idea how can I do that. Is it possible to be done in Nginx? Can you guide me to the correct path?

Answer (score 1):

Nginx needs to recognise the difference between URLs with a *locale* prefix and those without. In the example below, any URL where the first path element consists of exactly two characters, will be considered as containing a prefix.

This may be too broad for your requirement, in which case you will need to adapt the regular expression as required.

For example:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/(?<locale>\w\w)(/.*)$ $2 break;
    proxy_set_header Locale $locale;
    proxy_pass http://example.com;
}
```

On URLs that match the pattern containing a *locale*, the `rewrite...break` statement will both remove the prefix **and** set a named capture to its value.